# because of a lack of openness throughout the criminal justice system

Tags: meaning

*In a separate story in the Law Society Gazette, Strang is cited as telling a United Kingdom crowd that the UK criminal justice system is less open than the U.S.'s.*

*"Such miscarriages of justice would be harder to expose in the UK than the US, Strang said – because of a lack of openness throughout the criminal justice system," the Gazette reports. "He was speaking at the launch of an open justice charter drawn up by the Centre for Criminal Appeals, which says British justice is lagging behind even the poorest states in America when it comes to access to information."*

http://www.postcrescent.com/story/news/local/steven-avery/2017/02/10/dassey-supporters-eagerly-await-valentines-day/97541932/

I do not understand the statement regarding the difference between openness of judical systems in the UK and US in the two paragraphs above. From these two paragraphs I tend to understand it as if the openennes of law would be something wrong. But logically it is supposed to be the other way around, don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you understood it properly. This article highlights the difference between the American and the British criminal justice systems. They are saying that the British system is **significantly less open** than the American justice system, even saying that it lags behind the **poorest American states** in terms of openness, which if anyone is familiar with the reputation Southern Sheriffs have, is quite a low bar.

Look at the quote:

> "Such miscarriages of justice would be harder to expose in the UK than the US, Strang said"

He is saying that **because** the British system is **less open** than the American system **miscarriages of justice** (which are a very bad thing) are **harder to expose**. Which implies that a more open system is a positive thing, because it is easier to tell when an injustice has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if a more open system is positive thing why according to Strang the british system is less open and on the other hand – again acording to him – there is a lesser probability that the injustice occures in the UK.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the phrase I quoted. He doesn't talk at all about likelihood of an injustice occurring, he talks about how hard it is to **notice** when it has occurred. The operative phrase is "harder to expose", look up the definition of "expose", it means to reveal. He is saying that it is harder to notice injustice in the UK police system, because of how "closed" the system is.

Comment: Well at last! I understand it. Thank you once again for your perfect clarification. Yes, I misunderstood the meaning of "reveal".